# Pagebreak in parcolumn

Tags: page-breaking, parcolumns

How can I break columns/pages in a parcolumn environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}{2}

 \colchunk{
\begin{verse}
When shall we three meet again?\\
In thunder, lightning, or in rain?\\
\newpage
When the hurly-burly’s done,\\
When the battle’s lost and won
\end{verse}
}

 \colchunk{
\begin{verse}
Wenn kommen wir drey uns wieder entgegen,\\
In Donner, Blizen oder Regen?\\
Wenn das Mordgetuemmel schweigt,\\
Und der Sieg den Aufruhr beugt          
\end{verse}
}

\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Something like that but obviously `\pagebreak` or `newpage` does not work, and something like `\columnbreak` does not exist in parcolumns.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 4):

Here's my answer to my own question: With he `paracol` package you can use the command `\newpage`.

EDIT:

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{column}

\begin{verse}
When shall we three meet again?\\
In thunder, lightning, or in rain?\\
\newpage
When the hurly-burly’s done,\\
When the battle’s lost and won
\end{verse}
\end{column}


\begin{column}
\begin{verse}
Wenn kommen wir drey uns wieder entgegen,\\
In Donner, Blizen oder Regen?\\
Wenn das Mordgetuemmel schweigt,\\
Und der Sieg den Aufruhr beugt          
\end{verse}
\end{column}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a working example with you answer, to increase the value of the whole question ;)

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts (both gravatars and names are similar, but their reputation differ), which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).